# Выполнить функцию без задержки при первой загрузке страницы и далее ее же в setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

Я хочу выполнить функцию без задержки при первой загрузке страницы и далее эту же функцию хочу выполнять в `setInterval`.

Сейчас при готовности документа функция `showGraphTest` выполняется, но при первой загрузке страницы всё равно приходится ждать 30 секунд до его появления.

```
$(document).ready(function () {                
  setInterval(function(){
    showGraphTest();
  }, 30000, true);              
});
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать выполнение функции при первой загрузке страницы сразу а затем использовать `setInterval`?

Думал сделать цикл со счетчиком но что брать за основу, ума не приложу..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {                
    showGraphTest();

    setInterval(function(){
        showGraphTest();
    }, 30000);              
});
```

---

Либо

```
$(document).ready(function () {                
    showGraphTest();           
}); 


function showGraphTest() {
    ... 
    ...
    ...

    
    setTimeout(function(){
        showGraphTest();
    }, 30000);   
}
```

Comment: Точно. Спасибо!

Comment: Но зачем лишние функции? `$(document).ready(showGraphTest); function showGraphTest() { ... setInterval(showGraphTest, 30000);}`

Comment: ..................?

Comment: @AlexeyTen зачем `$(document).ready(func)`? Можно же `$(func)` :)

Comment: @EzioMercer точно. Давно jQuery не трогал =)

Answer (score 2):

Дополню второй вариант из ответа Алексея Шиманского.

Можно написать короче:

```js
$(function showGraphTest() {                
    // ... 
    
    setTimeout(showGraphTest, 30000);
});
```

`$(func)` это короткая запись для `$(document).ready(func)`.

Функции-выражению можно задать имя которое будет доступно внутри этой функции, так что можно не объявлять функцию отдельно, если она больше нигде не используется.